# NoSuchElementException when reading in file

Tags: java, file, sorting, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

This is my first time posting here. I've lurked quite a bit in the past, but can't seem to figure out what my problem is this time. This is for homework, and I have tried to solve it myself.

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String name = "", date = "", time = "";
        String month = "", day = "", year = "";

        ArrayList<Customer> customerArray = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        ArrayList<Date> dateArray = new ArrayList<Date>();

        File myFile = new File("./src/Program4/Customers.csv");

        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(myFile);

        while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
            String lineString = fileScan.nextLine();

            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(lineString);
            lineScan.useDelimiter(",");

            while (lineScan.hasNext()) {

//              if (lineScan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Name") == true
//                      || lineScan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Date") == true
//                      || lineScan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Time") == true) {                  
//                  lineScan.next();                    
//              } 
            //  else {      

                    name = lineScan.next();
                    date = lineScan.next();
                    time = lineScan.next();                     

                    Scanner dateScan = new Scanner(date);
                    dateScan.useDelimiter("/");

                    while (dateScan.hasNext()) {
                        month = dateScan.next();
                        day = dateScan.next();
                        year = dateScan.next();
                    }

                    Customer newCustomer = new Customer(name, date, time, day,
                            month);
                    customerArray.add(newCustomer);
                //}
            }
        } } }
```

The commented out part is just me seeing if that was the problem, as I was afraid the reason it wasn't working was because the header didn't have any "/". However, that wasn't the case. Here's a sample of the file I'm reading in:

```
Name    Date    Time
SK]CD[TUI   12/3/2014   5:41 AM
KXFPPHXPK   12/9/2014   7:43 AM
RVZTA[KLT   7/17/2014   9:35 AM
AUTVFXVZW   12/27/2014  2:39 AM
CFH\XBJRE   2/3/2014    9:51 AM
RT@KNCPHO   4/19/2014   8:42 AM
```

I have to sort them by date first, then time. I was using insertion sort but it was only reading the first digit of the date, it was ignoring the double digits. So, my solution was to have another scanner that broke up the date, then sort by that. I didn't get too far into that, though, because I'm getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at Program4.Driver.main(Driver.java:55)
```

Line 55 being:

```
day = dateScan.next();
```

So, no clue what the problem is. *Hopefully* my method is the best way to sort this, if it's not, it'd be nice if someone could save me some time and suggest an alternative.

Thanks!

====================

Edit:

Well, I figured out the initial problem. I added this:

```
    if (lineScan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Name") == true) {
        lineScan.nextLine(); } 
else {

    name = lineScan.next();
    date = lineScan.next();
    time = lineScan.next();
```

That somewhat fixed the problem, but I can't figure out why the scanner is skipping the first part of the file, the "name." "name" becomes the date, "date" becomes time, and "time" has nothing to grab so it throws no such element. I'm doing nextLine, so it shouldn't be eating the \n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homework hint:

You need to use your IDE's debugger to solve this.  Set a breakpoint at this line:

```
    Scanner dateScan = new Scanner(date);
```

and see what `date` is.  If that doesn't make the problem obvious to you, then use the debugger to execute the statements one at a time, watching what the `next` calls are returning.  (You may need to go around the outer loop a couple of times ...)

---

P.S.  I think I can see what the problem is ... but if you follow my advice, you should be able to find it yourself quickly.  And learn to use the debugger :-)

Comment: As I expected, it was crashing because the header doesn't have a "/". However, I un-commented my bit and now get the nosuchelement exception on this line:
|| lineScan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Date") == true
Debugging won't show me what goes wrong in this case. I'm also not sure how that's even happening? It should be checking whether or not it's true, seems odd that it would throw that.

Comment: @user3624480 Hint #2: the problem doesn't have anything to do with the file. And the debugger certainly would help with your problem.

Comment: If you can't understand what would be happening, use the debugger to help you.

Comment: @user3624480 The [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) would probably help a lot too

Comment: I edited the bottom of my post with some more code, if anyone can take a look. Figured out the initial problem, but am still stuck.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `lineScan.useDelimiter(",");`.  Your sample input file doesn't use a comma as the delimiter.

Comment: @StephenC - it's a .csv file, meaning an excel file. The cells are delimited by commas.

Comment: @user3624480 - The sample in your question is not a CSV file.  It is a file with fields separated by spaces.  How do you expect us to help you is you supply false / fake evidence?  You are on your own now ...

Comment: @StephenC - Sorry about that. If you look in the code I originally posted, you'll see that the file I'm reading in is .csv. The sample from the file is just the text that I copy pasted from Eclipse's text editor. It wasn't originally formatted the way it is now, another user edited my post and made it so.

Comment: Found out what the problem was. Turns out that my if statement, checking if scanner.next had a certain word, actually ate up said statement. I assumed it would only check it and use it in the next instance, but it checks by eating it up and then moves on. Seems silly that it does this but I found a way around it.